# Можно ли заполнить xml файл автоматически?

Tags: java, xml

Задача состоит в том чтобы xml заполнялся автоматически в зависимости от обновления определенного сайта.
То есть если на кино сайт постуапет новый фильм нужно что бы он так же добавился в xml файл.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, в чем состоит проблема, или укажите дополнительную информацию, чтобы стало ясно, в чем именно заключается вопрос. Сейчас практически невозможно понять, о чем именно вы спрашиваете. Чтобы разобраться, как правильно оформлять вопросы, посетите страницу "как задавать вопросы", http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Можно. javax.xml.parsers посмотрите, пример использования - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/

Comment: Я написал что надо посмотреть в сторону  javax.xml.parsers. Даже если ссылка протухнет, можно будет искать примеры использования  javax.xml.parsers